# Getting memory address in c++ without ampersand (&) operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, memory-address

I am implementing a default allocator for a simple containers library I'm writing, and I want to add an addressing-method that gets the memory address of the variable `x` that it works on, and that is also safe to use when `x` has *overloaded the &-operator.*

Looking into the MSVC STL source code I see that the function `__builtin_addressof(your_variable)` is used. Is this the only way? I also discovered the `address` method has been removed from the STL allocator in C++20, but I do not know if this was due to it not being used, or if there is a new and better method.

My implementation looks something like this:

```
namespace mem_core {

template <typename T>
const T* addressof(T& argument) noexcept {
    return __builtin_addressof(argument);
}

template <typename T>
const T* addressof(T&& arg) = delete;

//... more mem_core stuff

} //namespace mem_core end

template <typename T>
class allocator : public mem_core::base_allocator<T> { // refers to base_allocator interface
public:
    T* address(T& value) noexcept {
        return mem_core::addressof(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) for exactly this purpose